# Get a copy of the source code that the user sees

Tags: java

I search the web for hours, but could not find a helpful direction.

I need to use Java to create a code that "catches" the source code
that the user is asking from the browser.

**The application:** (the basic idea)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sourceCode;

    initialize();
    start();


    waitingForSourceCode();

    sourceCode = catchingTheSourceCode();

    System.out.println(sourceCode);

}
```

*Behind the scenes*:

the application "catches" the source code of the web page.
And print it to console.

**How to implement these methods?**

```
waitingForSourceCode();
catchingTheSourceCode();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `WebDriver`, you can get the page source using the `getPageSource()` method:

```
catchingTheSourceCode(){
   System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with webDrivers.
if the user uses chrome and then start my app,
will the webDriver work? 
or the user need to use the webDriver to surf the web? thanks.

Comment: Since ur new, webdriver drives the web browser engine, ie. if he uses chrome there will be  chromedriver you will need to use and it launches and performs operations on the chrome browser